# How can we represent a pandas.series value on Django?

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have the following code, where I am binning a Pandas dataframe into given number of bins:

```
def contibin(data, target, bins=10):
  #Empty Dataframe
  newDF,woeDF = pd.DataFrame(), pd.DataFrame()
    
  #Extract Column Names
  cols = data.columns
  for ivars in cols[~cols.isin([target])]:
        if (data[ivars].dtype.kind in 'bifc') and (len(np.unique(data[ivars]))>10):
            binned_x = pd.qcut(data[ivars], bins,  duplicates='drop')
            d0 = pd.DataFrame({'x': binned_x, 'y': data[target]})
            #print(d0)
        else:
            d0 = pd.DataFrame({'x': data[ivars], 'y': data[target]})
        d = d0.groupby("x", as_index=False).agg({"y": ["count", "sum"]})
        d.columns = ['Range', 'Total', 'No. of Good']
        d['No. of Bad'] = d['Total'] - d['No. of Good']
        d['Dist. of Good'] = np.maximum(d['No. of Good'], 0.5) / d['No. of Good'].sum()
        d['Dist. of Bad'] = np.maximum(d['No. of Bad'], 0.5) / d['No. of Bad'].sum()
        d['WoE'] = np.log(d['Dist. of Good']/d['Dist. of Bad'])
        d['IV'] = d['WoE'] * (d['Dist. of Good'] - d['Dist. of Bad'])
        #temp =pd.DataFrame({"Variable" : [ivars], "IV" : [d['IV'].sum()]}, columns = ["Variable", "IV"])
        #newDF=pd.concat([newDF,temp], axis=0)
        woeDF=pd.concat([woeDF,d], axis=0)
  return woeDF
```

The problem I am facing is when I try to integrate the code on front end using Django, I am not being able to represent woeDF['Range'] in Django the way I am able to see it normally. I tried converting the Pandas.Series to string, but it still isn't giving me what I want. To illustrate what I want to see in my frontend, I am attaching a picture of a sample table which I got by running this code on the Churn modelling Dataset.[The image of the table I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPTsN.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn the Dataframe in an array of objects using DataFrame.itertuples(index=False)

you will then be able to iterate through the dataframe in Jinja by accessing the columns via their names. See the below example in Python:

```
import pandas as pd

columns = {"name": ["john", "skip", "abu", "harry", "ben"],
           "age": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]}

df = pd.DataFrame(columns)
print(df)


df_objects = df.itertuples(index=False)
for person in df_objects:
    print("{0}: {1}".format(person.name, person.age))
```